# redux form server side validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I am stuck in setting the server-side validation of the redux form. I have a registration form and performing a client-side validation perfectly, but while in server-side validation I am unable to understand how to display the error message from the server with a respective input field.

**API request**

```
 const createMemberRegistration = user => {
  return dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: POST_REQUEST });
   processMemberRegistration(user)
   .then(user => {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTRATION_SUCCESS });
    dispatch(reset('memberregistration'));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTRATION_ERROR,payload:err });
  });
  };
 };
```

**Component**

```
 // submit button
 submitSignup(values) {
  var registerfields = JSON.stringify({
   first_name: values.firstname.trim(),
   last_name: values.lastname.trim(),
   email: values.email.trim(),
   password: values.password.trim()
 });
 if (registerfields) {
  this.props.createMemberRegistration(registerfields);
 }
}

//binding with redux form
const reduxmemberregistration = reduxForm({
 form: "memberregistration",
 validate:isvalidMemberRegistration,
 asyncValidate,
 enableReinitialize: true
})(MemberRegistration);
```

**Asycn function**

> stuck here what to do and how to validate with respective field

```
 const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch, props) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if(values.email){ // i get the value from the form,so what to do here?
    // so should i need to send request all the time to server for each 
      field for validation or what?
  }
 }
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a object that represents the state of you form and there you have some `error` property with same properties as fields on your form.

Let's say it looks like this

```
formState: {name : 'Test', error: {name: null} }
```

And you are rendering some error message under your inputs or decorating invalid input field with some class based on this `formState.error.name`.

In this situation you may get response object from server that also bears some input specific information and store it in e.g. `formState.serverError` error. So once data is fetched from backend you will post an action with this validation to Redux store, and if there are some errors, you will populate corresponding errors and will show appropriate error messages.

Condition for input field validity now will look like `formState.error.name && formState.serverError.name`

Comment: see this how to from reduxForm :) https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/submitvalidation/ it's suggested way for doing server-side validation as first sentence suggests

Comment: ok thanks,i am working on that but i was thinking to implement  [asyncvalidation](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/asyncvalidation/), can this be used?

Comment: as I can see this is used to see if the e.g. user name is free in the system. thus when user interacts with form you on the fly can do some search in backend to validate input.

Comment: ok... i think every time user interact with username field,it will hit to api for validation and but question is should it pass all the parameters to api whether they are blank and user didn't interact with other fields yet.How i dont know if you know then ,please let me know