# How to use data returned from the asyncValidate function in react and redux?

Tags: redux-form

I have created a form that is being validated using data from serve. If successful that validating function returns some data from server.

My Question is: **How can I use those data from server!? More specific, how can I store them in redux store!?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example of your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redux form server side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277215/redux-form-server-side-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!
I've got the solution that is, The validation functions may also pass store **dispatch function**, that may be used to dispatch action and the data to the reducer so as to update the state!!

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) =>
{
    axios(...).then(res => dispatch({type:'UPDATE_STATE', payload: res}))
}
```

thanks for all who viewed this question. Regards!!